# Using the binomial expansion to approximate a square root.

Tags: proof-verification, binomial-theorem

> Find the first four terms of the expansion $\sqrt{1-4x}$ in ascending powers of x.
>   Hence, approximate $\sqrt{6}$ to four decimal places.

I've expanded it to form this: $1-2x-2x^2-4x^3$

When approximating the value of $\sqrt{6}$, bearing in mind that for the expansion to be valid , $\left|x\right|<\frac{1}{4}$, I took out a value of $\sqrt{10}$ to form $\sqrt{10}\sqrt{0.6}$. Then, letting $x = 0.1$, I substituted $x$ into the expansion, then multiplied by $\sqrt{10}$ to find an approximate value for $\sqrt{6}$. Is there anything invalid about this? Why is it better to take out a factor of $2.5$?

Comment: If you have a way to calculate $\sqrt{10}$, then you don't *need* any of this.  You could instead pull out $\sqrt{9}$ or $\sqrt{4}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by that? If I pull out $\sqrt{4}$ and I try the calculations end up with 1.4218.

Comment: What this means its that this is whole process is meant to be a way of calculating square roots by hand, without a square root function that you can evaluate at $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we look at some arguments why taking out a    factor   $2.5$ is a convenient choice.

> **Problem:** We want to (manually)  approximate $\sqrt{6}$ by using the first few terms of the binomial series expansion of 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sqrt{1-4x}&=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-4x)^n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<\frac{1}{4}\\
> &= 1-2x-2x^2-4x^3+\cdots\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to apply (1) we are  looking for a number $y$ with
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1-4x}&=\sqrt{6y^2}=y\sqrt{6}\tag{2}\\
\color{blue}{\sqrt{6}}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{y}\sqrt{1-4x}}
\end{align*}

We see it is convenient to choose $y$ to be a square number which can be easily factored out from the root.  We obtain from (2)
\begin{align*}
1-4x&=6y^2\\
4x&=1-6y^2\\
\color{blue}{x}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}y^2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> When looking for a nice $y$  which fulfills (3) there are some aspects to consider:
>
> - We  have  to respect the radius of convergence $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$.
> - Since we want to calculate an approximation of $\sqrt{6}$ by hand we should take $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ with rather small numbers as numerator and denominator.
> - Last but not least: We want to find a value $x$ which provides a good approximation for $\sqrt{6}$.
>
> We will see it's not hard to find values which have these properties.

We see in (1) a good approximation is given if $x$ is close to $0$. If $x$ is close to zero we will also fulfill the convergence condition. $x$ close to zero means that in (3) we have to choose $y$ so that
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{2}y^2
\end{align*} 
is close to $\frac{1}{4}$. So,  $y^2$ is close to $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$. We have already   (1)  and (3) appropriately considered. Now we want to find  small natural  numbers $a,b$ so that
\begin{align*}
y^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\approx \frac{1}{6}
\end{align*}
This can be done easily. When going through small numbers of $a$ and $b$ whose squares are apart by a factor $6$ we might quickly come to $100$ and $16$. These are two small squares and we have $6\cdot 16=96$ close to $100$. That's all.

> Now it's time to harvest. We choose $y^2=\frac{16}{100}=\frac{4}{25}$ resp. $y=\frac{2}{5}$. We obtain for $x$ from (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> x=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}y^2=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{25}=\frac{1}{100}
> \end{align*}
>   We have now an appropriate value $x=\frac{1}{100}$ and we finally get  from (1) the approximation:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sqrt{6}} \approx \frac{5}{2}\left(1-2\cdot 10^{-2}-2\cdot 10^{-4}- 4\cdot 10^{-4}\right)\color{blue}{=2.449\,4}9
> \end{align*}
>
> We have $\sqrt{6}=\color{blue}{2.449\,4}89\,7\ldots$ with an approximation error $\approx 2.572\times 10^{-7}$. This result is quite impressive when considering that we have used just four terms of the binomial series.

At this point it might be clear that factoring out $2.5=\frac{5}{2}=\frac{1}{y}$ *is* a good choice.

*Note:* In a section about binomial series expansion in *[Journey through Genius](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/014014739X)* by W. Dunham the author cites Newton: *Extraction of roots are much shortened by this theorem*, indicating how valuable this technique was for Newton.